# How to access 'this' in Vuex store module state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

For example, say I have a "store" directory like this:

```
...
store
├── auth
│   └── user.js
└── index.js
...
```

**index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import {user} from './auth/user';

Vue.use(Vuex);

/* eslint-disable no-new */
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    user
  },
});

export default store;
```

Now in the `user` store I have some constants and other state variables in it's `state` prop. How can I access `state` props from within itself? For example `user` store may look like this:

**user.js**

```
export const user = {
  namespaced: true,

  state: {

    // hardcoded string assigned to user.state.constants.SOME_CONST
    constants: {
      SOME_CONST: 'testString'
    },

    // Another property where I would like to reference the constant above

    someOtherStateProp: {

      // Trying to access the constant in any of these ways throws
      // 'Uncaught ReferenceError: .... undefined'
      // Where '...' above is interchangeable with any root I try to access the constant from (this, state etc)

      test1: this.state.constants.SOME_CONST,
      test2: user.state.constants.SOME_CONST
      test3: state.constants.SOME_CONST
      test4: constants.SOME_CONST
      test5: SOME_CONST
      // .... etc. All the above throw ReferenceError's 
    }
  }
};
```

How can I reference `user.state.constants.SOME_CONST` from `user.state.someOtherStateProp.test1`?

Feel like I'm missing something very fundamental here.

Comment: Do you want to access these constants within any components

Comment: @VamsiKrishna, yes and that currently isn't an issue. I'm able to access them fine in components after mapping the state in component `computed` props

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be declarimg  the `CONSTANTS` object before exporting your module amd acceessing them as below

```
const CONSTANTS = {
    SOME_CONST: 'testString'
}

export const user = {
  namespaced: true,

  state: {

    // hardcoded string assigned to user.state.constants.SOME_CONST
    constants: CONSTANTS,

    // Another property where I would like to reference the constant above

    someOtherStateProp: {


      test1: CONSTANTS.SOME_CONST,
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by doing this in two steps.

```
let user = {
    namespaced: true,
    state: {
        SOME_CONST: 'testString'
    }
};

Object.assign(user, {
    state: {
        someOtherStateProp: {
            test1: user.state.SOME_CONST
        }
    }
});

export default user;
```

Read more about `Object.assign` here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign